# Why after adding social login to angular 6 npm start fails

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to add to my app Social Login.

I have tried to add all of this:

```
npm install --save angular-6-social-login-fixed
npm install --save angular-6-social-login
npm install --save angular-6-social-login-v2
```

And after this ,when i run >npm start

```
added 1 package from 1 contributor, removed 36 packages, updated 1 package and audited 23664 packages in 9.355s
found 45 vulnerabilities (12 low, 27 moderate, 6 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

(without adding  nothing to my code)
I am getting error:

```
 error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment'.
```

And many others error from my old modules like

```
error TS2315: Type 'CalendarEvent' is not generic.
error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'CalendarEvent'.
calendarUtils"' has no exported member 'GetWeekViewArgs'.
```

My  dependencies version

```
  "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
```

What i am missing?

Comment: I think you should install npm i moment

Comment: This will fix only one error of 100 that i getting from all my old components.Important to say that i dint have any error , only after adding  angular-6-social-login

Comment: have you installed moment js?

Comment: after i use npm install angular-moment moment --save it resolve only first error.i still have more then 100 error like error TS2315: Type 'CalendarEvent' is not generic.
error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'CalendarEvent'.
calendarUtils"' has no exported member 'GetWeekViewArgs'.  form my old components

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,but not the problem why this happens.
Make copy of working project,run npm install --save angular-6-social-login,then copy to this project your back up that you made before.

**This will not fix** the problem with (npm install),i still dint find the reason why when you use npm install (with any -social-login) it make changes to your project ,all packages ,components and other modules,but at least you can run you project with -social-login components with out errors.

*If any one know the reason why npm install make this mess and remove  Properties  from other components,please explane.